# Having issues with javaScript for loop for sorting of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am having issue with the following but has not figured out why.
I am just trying to write the hardcoded version into a for loop with the same number of iterations.

Hard coded for reference:

```
list = []
list.push(addSpace(test)) //0
test.shift()
list.push(addSpace(test)) //1
test.shift()
list.push(addSpace(test)) //2
test.shift()
list.push(addSpace(test)) //3
test.shift()
list.push(addSpace(test)) //4
test.shift()
list.push(addSpace(test)) //5
test.shift()
list.push(addSpace(test)) //6
test.shift()
list.push(addSpace(test)) //7
test.shift()
list.push(addSpace(test)) //8
let merged = [].concat.apply([], list);
console.log(merged);
console.log(`# of items in merged: ${merged.length}`)
```

Output:

```
[
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', 'D', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', '' ],  [ '', '', '', '', 'G' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', 'G' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', 'E', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', 'D', '', '', '' ], [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ]
]
# of items in merged: 41
```

I tried to put the above in a loop but why my loop did not complete?

```
function prepList(input) {
    let list = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        list.push(addSpace(input))
        test.shift()
    }
    list.push(addSpace(input))
    let merged = [].concat.apply([], list);
    return merged
}

console.log(prepList(test))
```

Output:

```
[
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', 'D', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ 'C', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '', '' ]
]
# of items in merged: 30
```

Array that was used:

```
let test= [
  [ 'C', 'C', 'C', '', 'C' ],
  [ '', 'C', '', 'C', '' ],
  [ 'C', 'C', 'C', '', 'C' ],
  [ '', 'C', '', 'D', '' ],
  [ 'C', 'C', 'C', '', 'C' ],
  [ '', 'C', '', 'C', '' ],
  [ 'C', 'C', '', 'G', 'G' ],
  [ '', 'E', '', 'D', 'C' ],
  [ 'C' ]
]
```

addSpace() function that was used:

```
function addSpace(arr) {
    let newList = []
    for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
            // to refresh the x everytime as splice will alter original x
            let x = ['', '', '', '']
            if (arr[i][j] == 'C') {
                x.splice(0, 0, arr[i][j])
                newList.push(x)
            } else if (arr[i][j] == 'D') {
                x.splice(1, 0, arr[i][j])
                newList.push(x)
            } else if (arr[i][j] == 'E') {
                x.splice(2, 0, arr[i][j])
                newList.push(x)
            } else if (arr[i][j] == 'F') {
                x.splice(3, 0, arr[i][j])
                newList.push(x)
            } else if (arr[i][j] == 'G') {
                x.splice(4, 0, arr[i][j])
                newList.push(x)
            } else if (arr[i][j] == '') {
                x.push('')
                newList.push(x)
            }
        }
        return newList
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful to know what you are trying to achieve in the first place. I'd suggest adding a code block with the result you would be expecting, and the actual result that you are encountering instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the list.length property because you mutate it using `test.shift()`!

```
const length = test.length; // this was added
for (let i=0; i<length; i++) {
  list.push(addSpace(test))
  test.shift()
}
```

```js
let test = [
  ['C', 'C', 'C', '', 'C'],
  ['', 'C', '', 'C', ''],
  ['C', 'C', 'C', '', 'C'],
  ['', 'C', '', 'D', ''],
  ['C', 'C', 'C', '', 'C'],
  ['', 'C', '', 'C', ''],
  ['C', 'C', '', 'G', 'G'],
  ['', 'E', '', 'D', 'C'],
  ['C']
]
list = []
const length = test.length; // this was added
for (let i=0; i<length; i++) {
  list.push(addSpace(test))
  test.shift()
}


let merged = [].concat.apply([], list);
console.log(merged);
console.log(`# of items in merged: ${merged.length}`)

function addSpace(arr) {
  let newList = []
  for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
      // to refresh the x everytime as splice will alter original x
      let x = ['', '', '', '']
      if (arr[i][j] == 'C') {
        x.splice(0, 0, arr[i][j])
        newList.push(x)
      } else if (arr[i][j] == 'D') {
        x.splice(1, 0, arr[i][j])
        newList.push(x)
      } else if (arr[i][j] == 'E') {
        x.splice(2, 0, arr[i][j])
        newList.push(x)
      } else if (arr[i][j] == 'F') {
        x.splice(3, 0, arr[i][j])
        newList.push(x)
      } else if (arr[i][j] == 'G') {
        x.splice(4, 0, arr[i][j])
        newList.push(x)
      } else if (arr[i][j] == '') {
        x.push('')
        newList.push(x)
      }
    }
    return newList
  }
}
```